# Adopt method parameters from constructor

Tags: c#, generics, methods, parameters, constructor

I have some classes that require a lot of parameters. I just created an example with two params to demonstrate my problem.

```
public class Zoo
{
    public List<Animal> Animals { get; set; }

    public Zoo()
    {
        Animals = new List<Animal>();
    }

    // Pass all parameters
    public void AddAnimal(string name, int age)
    {
        Animals.Add(new Animal(name, age));
    }

    // -> pseudo code <- Create the parameter reference automated -> pseudo code <-
    public void AddAnimal(params ...)
    {
        Animals.Add(new Animal(...));
    }
}

public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Animal(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

If I want to add an `Animal` to my `Zoo` I have 2 choices.

1. Pass all parameters to the `AddAnimal` Method
2. Add an `Animal` object to the `List`

As I said, I have a lot of params and a lot of "Animals".

Is it possible to reference the parameters of the `Animal` constructor without adding them manually to the AddAnimal method? (See: `-> pseudo code <-` in the first code block)

But I want to keep the method call.

```
Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
zoo.AddAnimal("Tom", 8);
```

Thanks in advance,
Jan

**Edit:**
For some reason, I want to prevent using one of the following methods:

```
zoo.AddAnimal(new Animal("Ben", 9));
zoo.AddAnimal(new Animal { "Ben", 9 }); // With empty constructor...
```

So, the final question is: Is it possible to just use **only** the constructor parameters **without** c&p them into the method?

Comment: Your `param object[]` approach is probably all you can get for automatic proxying of parameters (run-time type checking and boxing traded)... Read on [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) pattern as it probably what you trying to achieve... Or maybe t4 (templates for VS for code generation...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't proxy all of the individual constructor parameters automatically. But you can shift the burden to the caller:

```
public void Add(Animal animal)
{
    if(animal == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("animal");
    Animals.Add(animal);
}
...
zoo.Add(new Animal("Fred", 27));
```

Or you can just copy/paste the signature/constructor-call manually as per your "Pass all parameters" example.

Comment: Thats right, thaks. But, I want to prevent to create the objects outside of the "Zoo"-Class. As I said, I have a lot of animals with mutch more parameters.

Isn't it possible to pass only the parameters generic? Thanks!

Comment: @Jan no, it is not; besides, with the structures as shown, callers can already bypass everything: `zoo.Animals.Add(new Iguanodon());` (where `Iguanodon : Animal`, obviously)

Comment: +1 you can't get automatic generic proxying of all parameters AND compile time type checking...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov well, you could. But  you don't.

Answer (score 1):

I think the basic idea should be something like this:

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "[" + Name + ", " + Age + "]";
    }
}

public class Zoo
{
    public List<Animal> Animals { get; set; }

    public Zoo()
    {
        Animals = new List<Animal>();
    }

    // Pass all parameters
    public void AddAnimal(string name, int age)
    {
        Animal animal = new Animal
        {
            Name = name,
            Age = age
        };

        Animals.Add(animal);
    }

    // -> pseudo code <- Create the parameter reference automated -> pseudo code <-
    public void AddAnimal(params object[] animalProperties)
    {
        Animal animal = new Animal
        {
            Name = animalProperties[0] as string,
            Age = (animalProperties[1] as int?).Value
        };

        Animals.Add(animal);
    }
}

public class Example
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
        zoo.AddAnimal("Tom", 8);

        foreach (Animal a in zoo.Animals)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

But the best you can do this way is passing to your method generic objects and not specific types which in my opinion isn't a good idea (unless you are REALLY sure that you have type checked them before)

Another advice: if you have lots of properties as you say avoid the implementation of the constructor. I think is more manageable not having to deal with it (especially if some properties can be null).

Comment: Thanks. That would be possible, but I need a type safe solution. Because all parameters are imperative. In addition the (here called) Zoo-class is just there to hold data. It doesn't really have any kind of logic inside. Anyway: Thanks for your answer.